# laravel create not send data

Tags: php, laravel

Basically when i use

```
keycodes::create($data);
```

nothing happens and by nothing i mean nothing gets created

Model:

```
use HasFactory;

protected $table = 'keycodes';
protected $fillable = ['key', 'plan'];
```

controller:

```
$key = Random::generate(25, '123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
    return substr(chunk_split($key, 5, '-'), 0, 15);

    $data = array(
    'key' => substr(chunk_split($key, 5, '-'), 0, 15),
    'plan' => 'Basic'
    );
    keycodes::create($data);
```

migration:

```
$table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->char('key')->unique();
        $table->string('plan');
        $table->boolean('isUsed')->default(false);
```

Comment: `return substr(chunk_split($key, 5, '-'), 0, 15);` will stop execution of code after it. `keycodes::create($data);` is never reached

Answer (score 0):

As [brombeer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8034901/brombeer) already said, you are already returning a value from your code on the second line `return substr(chunk_split($key, 5, '-'), 0, 15);`, therefore the rest of the code is not reached and thus, the last line `keycodes::create($data);` is actually never executed.

Your code should simply be

```
$key = Random::generate(25, '123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
$data = array(
    'key' => substr(chunk_split($key, 5, '-'), 0, 15),
    'plan' => 'Basic'
);
keycodes::create($data);
```

Comment: Oh I see now, I should've known this.